# How do I add a user to a project in redmine?

Tags: redmine

I have users.  I have projects.  I go to Projects -> Settings -> Members

I get this message

```
No data to display
```

So... how do I add a user to a project?

Comment: I'm still seeing the "No data to display" message when trying to add members to project. I cannot figure out how to add a role to user. Also I can't add a user to a project from the user administration panel... same message "No data to display". Any advice?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add a new user to Redmine, you must go to "**Administration**" (at the top of the page) -> "**Users**".

If you want to assign an existing user to a project, you must select the project first and then go to "**Settings**" -> "**Members**". There you can assign a user and his/her role in the project.